# 220 outlet with no ground

Tags: electrical

I have a stove I am replacing that was direct wired.  When I went to put an outlet in, I found out it only has 3 wires, Black, Red, and White and no ground.  I have a hood right above it that is grounded.

Can I run the ground wire from the hood to the metal stove outlet box, bond it to the box with a screw in the back, and then to the ground terminal of the outlet for my stove?

I am a layman, so please keep it simple.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the outlet boxes for both the stove and the range hood?

Comment: The hood doesn't have a "box" per se, it simply has wires going into the hood that hook up to the wires inside the hood.  I have it out anyway, so not much to see there except wires hanging out of the wall.

Comment: The stove has a 4 x 4" metal box that has just 3 wires coming into it, Black, Red, and White.  Sorry I had to hook it all back up so my wife could use the stove or I could have gotten a picture.  It is all covered up now..

Comment: All the other outlets in our home are grounded, except for maybe the dryer (maybe my next task).  I checked the hood black wire and indeed it was grounded.  Not sure why they didn't do the stove.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you take the box for the stove back apart again and get us that photo?

Comment: I talked to someone that said the grounds all go back to the same place in the electrical panel and that is the way they used to ground houses anyway, by running a ground wire from one outlet to the next to the next.  I will try to get a photo the next time I take it apart, but what do you think about that?

Comment: Grounds indeed all do go back to the electrical panel, but we need that photo in order to see what wiring methods were used for the original wiring.  (There is also the issue of *sizing* ground wires correctly to carry the expected fault currents.)

Answer (score 1):

The range is going to need a #10 copper wire back to the panel, if your outlets are wired with #10 or something is going back to the same panel you can run a #10 to that location and it would be legal. If no #10 you need to go back to the service panel or your main grounding electrode within 5' of where it enters the home. The ground wire can take a different route than the power cable so that makes it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that has been asked many times. NEC Article 250.140 covers it which I have posted before. for your benefit I will post it again since it pretty much is the definitive answer to this problem.
[image]

[image]

Note the exception and the explanation and remember that it has to meet all the exception requirements before you are allowed to use it.

Good luck and Happy Holidays.

Comment: Thank you for all the information, but technical jargon is not my strong suit.  I guess from what I am reading I can share the ground, is that right?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to give me a breakdown of the technical information? What do the exceptions mean practically? I am not an electrician, just trying to ground one outlet with the ground from another. From the other answers I read, this is alright, but they too get off in to technical land and not really sure what they are talking about.

Comment: The answer may be definitive, but it's not accessible to a layman.  Further discussion and explanation should be added.